# Separate sub string from given String in C#

Tags: c#, string

I am having array of strings lets say

`{"Item Revision","Integer Item Revision","Double Item Revision"}` .

And I just want to exclude the `"revision"` part of strings .

Lets say If I am having `"Integer Item Revision"` string then I just want `"Integer Item"`. Here `"Revision"` part is common for the all the strings. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Is "Revision" is constant? or are you first looking for which word is common ?

Comment: @codetoshare yes you can say "Revision" is constant part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example fiddle. 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/vwJBkn

Using string.replace will work, if you know exactly what string you want to remove.

```
string[] array = new[] {"Item Revision","Integer Item Revision","Double Item Revision"};
    foreach (string i in array)
    {
//Replace console.writeline with your code. 
        Console.WriteLine (i.Replace("Revision", String.Empty));
    }
```

Comment: You should post the relevant part of code in the answer, just in case dotnetfiddle is down or goes away

Comment: Thanks. That is a good idea. To be honest, I myself updated the same fiddle by mistake, and had to redo it again.

Answer (score 7):

```
var array = new[] {"Item Revision","Integer Item Revision","Double Item Revision"};

array = array.Select(o=>o.Replace("Revision",string.Empty).Trim()).ToArray();
```

OR

```
var array = new[] {"Item Revision NotRevision"};
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\bRevision\b");
array = array.Select(o=>rgx.Replace(o,string.Empty).Trim()).ToArray();
```

Comment: how do you find the intersecting string "revision"? This might be dynamic, rather than fixed string.

Comment: @David read comment from the person who asked the question. It is fixed.

Comment: @David for more complicated cases - regex with `\b` around the word

Comment: @jitendragarg, thanks. Just curious to know, if this could be a more general solution.

Comment: Depends on the requirement then. Is it the common part in all strings? Is it supposed to be a database value? Is it supposed to come as a parameter? Are we supposed to calculate it using some logic? Answer will change based on the how we want to find that string. :/

Comment: @Backs your edited code doesn't seem to work on dotnet fiddle. I know it is not part of this question, but may I know what am I missing here?

Comment: @jitendragarg forgot to add `@` in pattern, thank you. https://dotnetfiddle.net/9pzJXb

Comment: Oh right. That `\ `  will require `@`. Can't believe I didn't notice it, especially when for last week, I am working on string literals only (registering client scripts). :/

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = "Item Revision".Replace(" Revision", "");
```

That'll strip away "Revision" and the leading space.

Comment: @David at no point does OP ask to "find" it. OP wrote "I just want to exclude the "revision" part of strings".

Comment: it might be. But I am just curious if there is a simple one-line solution to find this literal string? :)

Answer (score 4):

Can use for:

```
 String[] s = { "Item Revision", "Integer Item Revision", "Double Item Revision" };
            String[] tmp = new String[s.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                tmp[i] = s[i].Replace("Revision", "");
            }
```

Comment: Yes, we can update original array. I only want to keep original value, so i create a tmp array. Thanks.